# Place first item of grid at the end of row?

Tags: css

I have a row where everything is placed well, except for 1 item.
[image]
I want the remove button to be on the right, at the end, where I've scribbled some blue.
But if I try to align it to the right, then it just ends up being at the end of it's column, whereas I want it to be at the end of the entire row...
can someone please help?

Thank you in advance.

HTML

```
    <div class="basket-row">
        <div class="basket-image">
 <img src="@url" />
            }
        </div>
      
        <div class="basket-content">
          <div>
        <a href="#"
               class="icon icon-small icon-remove">
                </a>
                </div>
            <div class="title">
               <span>Jane Austen - I'm a very long title, aka product name</span>
            </div>

            <div class="stock grid-stock">
                <i class="icon icon-small icon-status-green"></i>
                In warehouse
            </div>

            <div class="basket-buttons input-group">
                <div class="quantity-group">
                    <span>@price</span>

                    <div class="quantity">
                        <a href="#"
                       class="button">
                            <i class="icon icon-small icon-subtract"></i>
                        </a>

                        <input type="text"
                           value="@quanity"
                           class="input" />

                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="icon icon-small icon-add"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                   50 EU
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.basket-row {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 16px;
    grid-template-columns: 70px 1fr;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebe5e8;
    padding: 16px;
}
.basket-row .basket-image {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.checkout .basket-row .basket-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}
.checkout .basket-row .basket-content .title {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
.basket-row .title {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 28px;
}

.basket-row .stock {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 6px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
    column-gap: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Please post a working example

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS property order

if a parent element has display flex or grid you can give it's child elements order.

example:

```
.parent{
display: grid;
}

.child-1{
order: 1;
}
.child-2{
order: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear in the given example.
I had given a minus margin to close button and placed it to end of row.Is this what you are trying to achieve.

```css
.basket-row {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 16px;
    grid-template-columns: 70px 1fr;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebe5e8;
    padding: 16px;
}
.basket-row .basket-image {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.checkout .basket-row .basket-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}
.checkout .basket-row .basket-content .title {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
.basket-row .title {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 28px;
}

.basket-row .stock {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 6px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.close-wrapper{
  text-align:right;
}
.close-wrapper{
  margin-right:-12px;
}
.basket-row{
  background:yellow;
}
.basket-content,.basket-image{
  background:#e4e4e4;
}
display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
    column-gap: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="basket-row">
        <div class="basket-image">
 <img src="@url" />
            }
        </div>
      
        <div class="basket-content">
          <div class="close-wrapper">
        <a href="#"
               class="icon icon-small icon-remove">
                </a>
                </div>
            <div class="title">
               <span>Jane Austen - I'm a very long title, aka product name</span>
            </div>

            <div class="stock grid-stock">
                <i class="icon icon-small icon-status-green"></i>
                In warehouse
            </div>

            <div class="basket-buttons input-group">
                <div class="quantity-group">
                    <span>@price</span>

                    <div class="quantity">
                        <a href="#"
                       class="button">
                            <i class="icon icon-small icon-subtract"></i>
                        </a>

                        <input type="text"
                           value="@quanity"
                           class="input" />

                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="icon icon-small icon-add"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                   50 EU
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<div class="close-wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="icon icon-small icon-remove"></a>
</div>

.close-wrapper{
  text-align:right;
}
.close-wrapper{
  margin-right:-12px;
}
```

These are the two changes i had added to your code. yellow background is the row and grey backgrounds are the columns.
If this is not what you are trying to achieve then please give a clear view of the design.